# C# - Representing multiple arrays as a List<Tuple<x,x,x,x,>>

Tags: c#, .net

We have an old framework called CAGen in which legacy mainframe devs create "CABS" and then .NET code is generated to allow consumption in more modern languages.  Unfortunately it seems to take thew rows of results from the underlying database and rather than create an object with properties its "groups" are generated as multiple arrays (one per column) all of equal length along with a Length value so we know how many rows to read.

Rather than manually handle reach column I'd like to build some kind of wrapper class which takes all the arrays and exposes them as if they were a List.  I'd like it to be compile safe and was thinking using Tuples.  Rather than start from scratch I'm wondering if anyone knows of a neat approach or existing component that may help ease the burden?

Comment: Why use tuples rather than create your own class with the relevant properties?

Comment: Tuple is inmutable, which means, you can't change it content. Each time you'll be in need to create new Tuple. So, there's no chance to execute something like this: `MyTuple.Item1="whatever";`

Comment: That's still possible with your own class (private setters from constructor, public getters)

Comment: Have you thought creating a class that overrides List<object[]>, and then in the class include some overrides to handle the different field types?

Comment: My thought on Tuples is that it already contains all the overrides for the varying number of parameters saving me the hassle to cater for x number of columns.  The main consideration is that in my first case I have an int[] and a bool[], but then using that wrapper in another scenario I'll have decimal[], int[], bool[], string[], string[], string[], string[], DateTime?[], ...  Then again even wrapping Tuples I'd still probably have to provide the telescoping overloads

Comment: Righto, maybe I'll just go with defining the RowClassA then poke that into a List<RowClassA> wrapper with some smarts inside that knows how to grab the arbitrary number of properties internal.  Bit of reflection perhaps.  I'll tinker

Comment: Actually Gary, List<object[]> might be the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE: Definitive answer**
Thanks to Linq and some insight from a colleague it's a one liner to wrap any  number of arrays onto a model for easy iteration with a foreach:

```
int[] ids = new int[5] { 5, 3, 2, 1, 4 };
string[] names = new string[5] { "John", "Joan", "Bob", "Mark", "Someone" };
bool[] bools = new bool[5] { true, true, false, true, false };

var items = ids.ToList().Select(
    (id, index) => 
        new 
        { 
            ID = id, 
            Name = names[index], 
            YesOrNo = bools[index] 
        });
```

==========================================================

Thanks for the idea Gary.
Here's what I came up with:

```
public class MultiListWrapper : List<object[]>
{
    private Type[] fieldTypes;
    public MultiListWrapper(int length, params object[] fields)
    {
        fieldTypes = fields.Select(f => f.GetType()).ToArray();

        for (int r = 0; r < length; r++)
        {
            var row = new object[fields.Length];
            for (int f = 0; f < fields.Length; f++)
            {
                var field = fields[f];
                row[f] = (field as Array).GetValue(r);
            }
            Add(row);
        }
    }
}
```

As it is the underlying values once instantiated still do show up as type  **object** but I'm thinking that I could still provide a property or **IEnumerable< TModel > Get< TModel >()** method would would use the fieldTypes array as validation / casting to the requested model for each row and perhaps rather than subclass a List, just use compostition and hold the list internally to force casting for the consumer.

At any rate, it seems like two lines of code now to wrap the multiple arrays to a nice object which can be enumerated and used like any old Enumerable POCO.

========================================
**Edit:**

So I've finished off the implementation, thought I'd post it here in case anyone was interested:

```
public class MultiListWrapper<T> : IEnumerable<T>
    where T : class, new()
{
    private List<object[]> list = new List<object[]>();
    private Type[] fieldTypes;
    private int length = 0;

    public MultiListWrapper(int length, params object[] fields)
    {
        this.length = length;
        fieldTypes = fields.Select(f => f.GetType()).ToArray();

        for (int r = 0; r < length; r++)
        {
            var row = new object[fields.Length];
            for (int f = 0; f < fields.Length; f++)
            {
                var field = fields[f];
                row[f] = (field as Array).GetValue(r);
            }
            list.Add(row);
        }

    }

    public int Count { get { return length; } }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            if (index >= length)
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();

            // Create the return item
            var item = new T();
            var properties = item.GetType().GetProperties();

            // Get fields from list item
            var listItem = list[index];
            for (int i = 0; i < listItem.Length; i++)
            {
                if(properties[i].PropertyType.FullName != fieldTypes[i].FullName.Replace("[]", string.Empty))
                    throw new SettingsPropertyWrongTypeException(
                        string.Format("The type for Property '{0}' on the requested model '{1}' doesn't match the underlying list item property type", 
                        properties[i].Name,
                        typeof(T).FullName));

                properties[i].SetValue(item, listItem[i]);

            }

            return item;
        }
    }


    private MultiListWrapperEnumerator<T> _enumerator;
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        if (_enumerator == default(MultiListWrapperEnumerator<T>))
        {
            _enumerator = new MultiListWrapperEnumerator<T>(this);
        }

        return _enumerator;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }


    #region Enumerator for the wrapper

    private class MultiListWrapperEnumerator<T> : IEnumerator<T>
    where T : class, new()
    {
        private MultiListWrapper<T> _listWrapper;
        private int _index;

        public MultiListWrapperEnumerator(MultiListWrapper<T> listWrapper)
        {
            _listWrapper = listWrapper;
            _index = -1;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {

        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            _index++;
            if (_index >= _listWrapper.Count)
                return false;

            return true;
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            _index = -1;
        }

        public T Current
        {
            get { return _listWrapper[_index]; }
            private set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        object IEnumerator.Current
        {
            get { return Current; }
        }
    }

    #endregion

}
```

To use it you create you various arrays (all the same length), create a POCO model to represent "rows" against the array elements then pass them all into the wrapper:

```
public class TheModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool YesOrNo { get; set; }
}



int[] ids = new int[5] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
string[] names = new string[5] { "John", "Joan", "Bob", "Mark", "Someone" };
bool[] bools = new bool[5] { true, true, false, true, false };

var wrappedList = new MultiListWrapper<TheModel>(5, ids, names, bools);
```

then request an element like so:

```
var bob = wrappedList[2];
```

it's enumerable as well:

```
foreach (var item in wrappedList)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", item.Id, item.Name, item.YesOrNo);
}
```

Checks are being done in the indexer to ensure the types on the array elements match the property type on the Model.  Ordering is going to be important with the order of the array parameters on the constructor needing to match the order the Model elements are declared.